# Loop not waiting for resolution of promise (containing nested firebase call)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, state

I am trying to make a Firebase database call inside of a loop and an outer firebase call.  The inner Firebase database call is using data returned from the outer firebase call and the loop, which is why it is run within the outer one.  The results then should be set into the state.

**Problem**
The value that is being retrieved in the inner Firebase database call is not being set in the state.

**Theory**
Since Firebase database calls are asynchronous, my guess is that the inner Firebase database call does not finish before the loop completes and sets the state.
Therefore, I created a promise for the inner Firebase database call, so that the loop would wait for the call to finish before moving onto the next item.
However, the value retrieved is still not being set.

Does anyone know why the loop does not wait for promise containing call to Firebase database?

**MY ATTEMPT**

```
userRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {
  var snap = [];
  // loop through each branch received from firebase
  snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
    var firstThingsFirst = data.val().firstThingsFirst;
    var someID = data.val().someID;
    var myPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      userRef.child('somechild').child(someID).once('value').then(function(newSnapshot) {
        console.log("newSnapshot = (below)");
        console.log(newSnapshot.val());
        resolve(newSnapshot.val());
      }, function(error) {
        // Something went wrong.
        console.error("error (below)");
        console.error(error);
        reject("noValueFound")
      });
    });
    var someValue = "";
    myPromise.then(function(valueRetrieved) {
      console.log(".then of promise is running...");
      console.log("valueRetrieved = (below)");
      console.log(valueRetrieved);
      someValue = this.checkUndefined(valueRetrieved);
    }.bind(this));
    var array = {"firstThingsFirst": firstThingsFirst, "someValue": someValue};
    snap.push(array);
  });
  this.setState({
    snapshots: snap
  });
}.bind(this));
```

**Alternative Attempt:**

```
userRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {
  var snap = [];
  // loop through each branch received from firebase
  snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
    var firstThingsFirst = data.val().firstThingsFirst;
    var someID = data.val().someID;
    var someValue = this.fetchValueByID(someID);

    var array = {"firstThingsFirst": firstThingsFirst, "someValue": someValue};
    snap.push(array);
  });
  this.setState({
    snapshots: snap
  });
}.bind(this));

fetchValueByID(someID) {
  userProfileRef.child('someChild').child(someID).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    console.log("snapshot (fetchValueByID) = (below)");
    console.log(snapshot.val());
    return snapshot.val();
  })
}
```

I have also tried the approaches recommended by Firebase:

- https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/keeping-our-promises-and-callbacks_76.html

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does anyone know why the loop does not wait for promise containing call to Firebase database?

The reason for this is that you require `setState` to be called after all the fetches are done. But, your code doesn't do anything to *wait*. You just carry on with the loop and once it's done, call `setState`. You never really know whether your fetches completed or not. You need a way to *wait* for all the the fetches. In a nutshell, there is a problem because of mixing of synchronous and asynchronous code.

You can try this. The idea is to map all the `fetchValueByID` (I've added a `return` in the beginning) calls into an array of promises and then wait for *all* of them to resolve (using [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)) *before* doing `setState`

```
userRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {
  // loop through each branch received from firebase
  // AND map to array of promises
  var promises = [];
  snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
    var firstThingsFirst = data.val().firstThingsFirst;
    var someID = data.val().someID;
    promises.push(this.fetchValueByID(someID).then(function(someValue) {
      return {
        "firstThingsFirst": firstThingsFirst,
        "someValue": someValue
      };
    }));
  });

  // Wait for all promises to resolve
  Promise.all(promises).then(function(results) {
    this.setState({
      snapshots: results
    });
  }.bind(this))

}.bind(this));

fetchValueByID(someID) {
  // Notice the return here
  return userProfileRef.child('someChild').child(someID).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    console.log("snapshot (fetchValueByID) = (below)");
    console.log(snapshot.val());
    return snapshot.val();
  })
}
```

I've faked all the possible data and converted my solution to a simple-to-understand snippet below

```js
var promises = [];
// Faking the snapshot
[{
  a: 1,
  b: 10
}, {
  a: 2,
  b: 20
}].forEach(function(data) {
  var firstThingsFirst = data.a
  var someID = data.b
  promises.push(fetchValueByID(someID).then(function(someValue) {
    return {
      "firstThingsFirst": firstThingsFirst,
      "someValue": someValue
    };
  }));
});

// Wait for all promises to resolve
Promise.all(promises).then(function(results) {
  console.log(results);
});

function fetchValueByID(someID) {
  // Dummy Promise resolution
  // Notice the return here
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      // Dummy manipulation
      resolve(someID * 100);
    });
  }).then(function(snapshot) {
    console.log("snapshot (fetchValueByID) = (below)");
    console.log(snapshot);
    return snapshot;
  })
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can run `.map` on snapshot data from firebase so I tried using the firebase function `.forEach`, which does loop through the data but I get an error that `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: undefined is not a function` when the `Promise.all(promises).then(function(results) {
  console.log(results);
});` line tries to run. Still trying to resolve this error but any suggestions would be greatly appreciated too!

Comment: I missed the fact that `snapshot` is not an `Array`. I've edited the code to create `promises` as an `Array` while using `forEach` on `snapshot`.

Comment: Ah, I just tried this same revision as well! Yes, `.push`ing the promises into an array worked perfectly!  My first time using `Promise.all()` and feeling good about it now!  Many Thanks!

Comment: Good to hear that! Hope the working example helped you understand it better.

Comment: yes!  It was great to see it in action.  Thanks for taking the time to help me understand more :)